# Inference for the average treatment effect for Bernoulli trial

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, treatment-effect, clinical-trials, random-allocation

In the [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/causal-inference-for-statistics-social-and-biomedical-sciences/71126BE90C58F1A431FE9B2DD07938AB) of Imbens and Rubin, they discuss four common classes of assignment mechanisms
that fit into this framework: Bernoulli trials, completely randomized experiments,
stratified randomized experiments, and pairwise randomized experiments. Chapters 5, 6, 7, and 8 are then for completely randomized experiments. Chapter 9 and 10 are for the last two experiments, respectively. This makes me curious, why the book does not discuss inference for the Bernoulli trials. The following might be the reason.

> One common disadvantage of Bernoulli trials is that, because of the
> independence of the assignment across all units, there is always a
> positive probability (although small even in modest samples, and
> essentially zero in large samples) that all units will receive the
> same treatment. In that case, there will be no evidence in the data
> about the potential outcome values under the treatment that is not
> represented in the data. Even when there is a single unit being
> assigned one treatment and many assigned the other treatment, there
> will be limited evidence about the potential outcomes under the former
> treatment.

However, If I am correct, these are reasons why this Bernoulli randomization is not common in practice (In contrast, some [papers](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0197245688900463?via%3Dihub) suggests that Bernoulli trial (also simple randomization) can be used when sample size is 200 or more).

But do the reasons also prevent making inference for the average treatment effect?